# How to pivot Pandas DataFrame on distinct values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe p:

```
 p = {'ID': {0: 'A', 1: 'A',  2: 'B', 3: 'B'},
 'col1': {0: 8.0, 1: 237.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0},
 'col2': {0: 15.0, 1: -9.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 5.0},
 'col3': {0: 8.0, 1: 237.0, 2: -1.0, 3: -62.0},
 'col4': {0: -13.0, 1: 94.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 0.0},
 'col5': {0: 8.0, 1: 237.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 3.0},
 'col6': {0: 'car', 1: 'truck', 2: 'car', 3: 'truck'}}
p = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(p)
```

and I am wanting to pivot or unstack on col6:

```
p.pivot(columns='col6')
```

However that returns a bunch of 'None' and 'NaN':

```
    ID  col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
col6    car truck   car truck   car truck   car truck   car truck   car truck
0   A   None    8.0 NaN 15.0    NaN 8.0 NaN -13.0   NaN 8.0 NaN
1   None    A   NaN 237.0   NaN -9.0    NaN 237.0   NaN 94.0    NaN 237.0
2   B   None    2.0 NaN 0.0 NaN -1.0    NaN 2.0 NaN 3.0 NaN
3   None    B   NaN 2.0 NaN 5.0 NaN -62.0   NaN 0.0 NaN 3.0
```

What I am looking for is a table structure like this (with the values filled in):

```
ID    car_col1   truck_col1   car_col2    truck_col2
A
B
```

So I would only have one unique ID per line.  There will always be 2 IDs, one per car/Truck.

Comment: `p.pivot(index='ID', columns='col6')`

Answer (score 0):

Given the following input:

```
p = {'ID': {0: 'A', 1: 'A',  2: 'B', 3: 'B'},
 'col1': {0: 8.0, 1: 237.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0},
 'col2': {0: 15.0, 1: -9.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 5.0},
 'col3': {0: 8.0, 1: 237.0, 2: -1.0, 3: -62.0},
 'col4': {0: -13.0, 1: 94.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 0.0},
 'col5': {0: 8.0, 1: 237.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 3.0},
 'col6': {0: 'car', 1: 'truck', 2: 'car', 3: 'truck'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(p)

  ID   col1  col2   col3  col4   col5   col6
0  A    8.0  15.0    8.0 -13.0    8.0    car
1  A  237.0  -9.0  237.0  94.0  237.0  truck
2  B    2.0   0.0   -1.0   2.0    3.0    car
3  B    2.0   5.0  -62.0   0.0    3.0  truck
```

try this code:

```
df.pivot(index='ID', columns='col6')
```

and gives:

```
     col1         col2       col3         col4       col5       
col6  car  truck   car truck  car  truck   car truck  car  truck
ID                                                              
A     8.0  237.0  15.0  -9.0  8.0  237.0 -13.0  94.0  8.0  237.0
B     2.0    2.0   0.0   5.0 -1.0  -62.0   2.0   0.0  3.0    3.0
```

Comment: How do I 'reset' the column names?

Comment: `new_df.columns = [f'{y}_{x}' for x,y in new_df.columns]`

Comment: Do you mean how to return the column names to [col1, col2 ...]? If you mean this, after the pivot operation you just do: `df.columns = [col[0] for col in df.columns]`

Comment: If instead you mean [col1_car, col1_truck, col2_car ...] etc do as you suggested @QuangHoang: `df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a,b in df.columns]
`